# What does this C++ / C++11 construction mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got this short snippet of code. I don't understand what this construction means. I know this snippet of code reads numbers from input and counts its frequency in an unordered_map. But what is `[&]`? And what is the meaning of `(int x)`? What does the `input(cin)` stand for? I mean the "cin" in parentheses? And how can for_each iterate from `input(cin)` to empty eof parameter? I don't understand of this whole construction.

```
unordered_map<int,int> frequency;
istream_iterator<int> input(cin);
istream_iterator<int> eof;

for_each(input, eof, [&] (int x)
    { frequency[x]++; });
```

Comment: Check out the new c++ lamda operator ! It's awesome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`istream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istream_iterator/) allows you to iteratively extract items from an [`istream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/), which you pass in to the constructor. The `eof` object is explained thus:

> A special value for this iterator exists: the end-of-stream; When an
>   iterator is set to this value has either reached the end of the stream
>   (operator void* applied to the stream returns false) or has been
>   constructed using its default constructor (without associating it with
>   any basic_istream object).

[`for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) is a loop construct that takes iterator #1 and increments it until it becomes equal with iterator #2. Here it takes the iterator that wraps standard input [`cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) and increments it (which translates to extracting items) until there is no more input to consume -- this makes `input` compare equal to `eof` and the loop ends.

The construct `[&] (int x) { frequency[x]++; }` is an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B); it is simply a shorthand way to write functions inline. Approximately the same effect could be achieved with

```
unordered_map<int,int> frequency; // this NEEDS to be global now
istream_iterator<int> input(cin);
istream_iterator<int> eof;

void consume(int x) {
    frequency[x]++;
}

for_each(input, eof, consume);
```

So in a nutshell: this code reads integers from standard input until all available data is consumed, keeping a count of each integer's appearance frequency in a map.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts of your question.

1. The first one concerns stream iterators. An `std::istream_iterator<T>` is constructed from some `std::istream & s`, and upon dereferencing, it behaves like `{ T x; s >> x; return x; }`. Once the extraction fails, the iterator becomes equal to a default-constructed iterator, which serves as the "end" iterator.

   Stream iterators allow you to treat a stream as a container of tokens. For example:

   ```
   std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                      std::istream_iterator<int>());

   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
   ```
2. C++11 introduces *lambda expressions*, which define anonymous functions or functors (called *closures*). A simple one looks like this:

   ```
   auto f = [](int a, int b) -> double { return double(a) / double(b); };

   auto q = f(1, 2);  // q == 0.5
   ```

   This `f` could have been written as an ordinary, free function, but the free function would have had to appear at namespace scope or as a static member function of a local class. (Which is in fact what the type of the lambda expression is!) Note that the type of a lambda expression is unknowable, and can only be captured via the new `auto` keyword.

   Lambdas become more useful when they act as complex function *objects* which can capture ambient state. Your example could have been written like this:

   ```
   auto f = [&frequency](int x) -> void { ++frequency[x]; };
   ```

   The variables that appear in between the first square brackets are *captured*. This lambda is equivalent to the following local class and object:

   ```
   struct F
   {
       F(std::unordered_map<int, int> & m) : m_(m) { }
       void operator()(int x) { ++m_[x]; }
   private:
       std::unordered_map<int, int> & m_;
   } f;
   ```

Variables without `&` in the capture list are captured by value, i.e. a copy is made in the closure object. As a short-hand, you can say `[=]` or `[&]` to capture *everything* respectively by value or by reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is STL **std::for_each** (non-C++11) iterating **input** until is equals to **eof**; calling lambda `[&] (int x) { frequency[x]++; }` for each value

So, this code calculate frequency of characters in istream; saving them into **map**